# Integral of a product of Laguerre polynomials

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, integration, orthogonal-polynomials

In order to estimate the non linear term in a particular PDE, I have to decompose $L_k^\alpha(x)^3\cdot x^{-\delta}$ (with $0<\delta<\alpha+1$) into a basis consisting of Laguerre polynomials $L_n^\alpha(x)$.  To perform the decomposition I have to compute the following definite integral

$$
T_n:=\int_0^\infty L_k^\alpha(x)^3 L_n^\alpha(x)x^{\alpha-\delta}e^{-x}dx\,.
$$

Is there a closed form formula for the above integral or a way to obtain it?

EDIT:

I have found a [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01218891) by Artur Erdélyi where he gives a general formula for an integral of a product of $n$ Laguerre polynomials.  Unfortunately, the result is presented in terms of Lauricella hypergeometric function and is not easily computable in the case of $T_n$.  There are also some papers on a product of three Laguerre polynomials, which might be used to simplify $T_n$ but I won't be able to read them thoroughly for several days now.

Comment: Note that the (weighted) integral of a product of Laguerre polynomias has a combinatorial meaning, (at least for $\alpha=0$); see this answer and the link therein: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36824/applications-of-measure-integration-and-banach-spaces-to-combinatorics/36846#36846

Comment: The explicit answer is known for your case if $3\alpha=-\delta$.

Comment: Is explicit formula exactly what you need for estimating?

Answer (score 1):

Maple finds the integral under consideration for concrete values of $n$ and $k$, producing  huge outputs. For example, $$restart; with(orthopoly):VectorCalculus:-int(L(2, alpha, x)^3*L(3, alpha, x)*x^{alpha-delta}*exp(-x), x = 0 .. infinity) assuming\, alpha > delta-1 $$ gives $$-1/48\,\Gamma  \left( 4+\alpha-\delta \right)  \left( {\delta}^{6}+12
\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{4}-27\,{\delta}^{5}+30\,{\alpha}^{2}{\delta}^{2}-
208\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{3}+319\,{\delta}^{4}+8\,{\alpha}^{3}-246\,{
\alpha}^{2}\delta+1422\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{2}-2081\,{\delta}^{3}+532\,{
\alpha}^{2}-4466\,\alpha\,\delta+7828\,{\delta}^{2}+5380\,\alpha-15976
\,\delta+13736 \right) +$$  $$1/48\,\Gamma  \left( \alpha-\delta+1 \right) 
 \left( \alpha+3 \right)  \left( {\alpha}^{2}{\delta}^{6}-3\,\alpha\,{
\delta}^{7}+3\,{\delta}^{8}+12\,{\alpha}^{3}{\delta}^{4}-63\,{\alpha}^
{2}{\delta}^{5}+120\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{6}-66\,{\delta}^{7}+30\,{\alpha
}^{4}{\delta}^{2}-298\,{\alpha}^{3}{\delta}^{3}+1069\,{\alpha}^{2}{
\delta}^{4}-1464\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{5}+698\,{\delta}^{6}+8\,{\alpha}^{
5}-270\,{\alpha}^{4}\delta+2274\,{\alpha}^{3}{\delta}^{2}-7067\,{
\alpha}^{2}{\delta}^{3}+9342\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{4}-4356\,{\delta}^{5}+
556\,{\alpha}^{4}-6356\,{\alpha}^{3}\delta+23458\,{\alpha}^{2}{\delta}
^{2}-34181\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{3}+17171\,{\delta}^{4}+6176\,{\alpha}^{3
}-38038\,{\alpha}^{2}\delta+72258\,\alpha\,{\delta}^{2}-42898\,{\delta
}^{3}+23980\,{\alpha}^{2}-81016\,\alpha\,\delta+65264\,{\delta}^{2}+
36800\,\alpha-54248\,\delta+18448 \right)
 .$$

Comment: Integrand is a polynomial in $x$ times $x^{\alpha-\delta}e^{-x}$.  Such integral is always computable explicitly for any chosen $n$ and $k$.  The question is, can we present the result in a compact form without fixing $n$ and $k$ beforehand.

Comment: MATHEMATICA or MAPLE do not work?