# Sums of products over restricted set compositions

Tags: co.combinatorics

For any two nonconstant functions $f,g$ on the positive integers, e.g., polynomials, first note that the product of the following evaluation binomials can be expanded as
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n (f(k)+g(k)) = \sum_{(I,J)}\prod_{i\in I}f(i)\prod_{j\in J}g(j)
$$
where the sum is over all set compositions $(I,J)$ of $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, i.e., ordered 2-partitions of the set $[n]$.

I am very much interested in knowing whether anything has been studied about how to handle the following generalization of the right hand side of such an expression (like simplifications, alternative forms, relation to recursion or generating functions, etc.): restrict the sum to the compositions that satisfy certain set cardinality condition $c(I,J)=h$ (for example restrict the sum to $|I|=h$ for a fixed number $h$, or to the case $|(I+a)\cap (J+b)|=h$, where the sum of a positive or negative integer $a,b$ on the subsets $I,J$ is understood as element-wise), and introduce integer weights $W_h$ that depend only on the size of this condition, i.e., I am interested in whether anything is known about expressions of the form
$$
\sum_h\sum_{\substack{(I,J) \\ c(I,J)=h}} W_h \prod_{i\in I}f(i)\prod_{j\in J}g(j).
$$

There are results about sums of products of a function over restricted compositions of a number (e.g. the papers by Eger (2013) on extended binomial coefficients), but the previous expression is about weighted sums of products over restricted compositions of a set.

Comment: Consider the simplest nontrivial case: $g(j)=1$ for all $j$, $f(i) = x_i$, and $W_h = 1$ if $h=k$ and $0$ otherwise (where I am interpreting the restriction $c(I,J)=h$ as $|I|=h$ like you suggested first). Then your expression reduces to $\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} x_{i_1} x_{i_2} \cdots x_{i_k}$, in other words, to the elementary symmetric polynomial $e_k (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). What expression could you hope for even in this case?

Comment: (I’m omitting $J$ since it is $[n]\setminus I$). Is the case where $c:2^{[n]}\to \mathbb R$  is an additive set function , of interest?

Comment: @SamHopkins, yes giving an expression of the last formula in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials would be already enough and very useful. Indeed the case $|I|=h$ can in general be given such a form for simple f,g (notice they must be nonconstant, for example $f(i)=2n-2-i, g(j)=j-1$) by introducing some generic variable into the expression and extracting the appropriate degree.

Comment: @PietroMajer, yes, any insights for the latter general expression are of interest, even though I especially look for $c$ functions which can be interpreted as giving a constraint on intersections of the $I,J$ subsets of $[n]$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hopefully not too involute thoughts for a quite general form of weights, inspired by a similar particular [computation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36824/applications-of-measure-integration-and-banach-spaces-to-combinatorics/36846#36846). To be slightly more general, suppose we are multiplying some sums of terms (say, of complex numbers). Let $a:J\to \mathbb C$ be the family of all terms. Let $\{J_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a partition of the index set $J$, described as fibres of a map $p:J\to\Lambda$, i.e. $J_\lambda=p^{-1}(\lambda)$; denote  $\Gamma=\{\sigma: \Lambda\to J : p\circ\sigma={\bf 1}_{\Lambda}\}= \prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda} J_\lambda$ the set of all sections of $p$ (i.e. the choice functions for the partition). Then
a $\prod\sum \bf 2\sum\prod$ expansion formula  writes

$$\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\sum_{j\in J_\lambda}a(j)=\sum_{\sigma\in\Gamma}\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}a(\sigma(\lambda)).$$

Now suppose we have to deal with a weighted sum of the form
$$\sum_{\sigma\in\Gamma}W_\sigma\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}a(\sigma(\lambda)). $$
Since every $\sigma\in \Gamma$  only depends on the subset $\sigma(\Lambda)\subset J$, we have $W_\sigma=w(\sigma(\Lambda))$ for some set-function $w:2^J\to \mathbb C$. Suppose we can write it in the form of moments of some linear functional  $\psi:\mathbb C[x]\to\mathbb C$, namely
$$w(S)=\langle\psi, x^{\mu(S)}\rangle$$
where $\mu:2^J\to\mathbb N$ is an *additive* set-function, $\mu(S)=\sum_{j\in S} \mu(j).$ Now for every $S\subset J$ define polynomials $$P_S(x):=\sum_{j\in S}a(j)x^{\mu(j)}.$$
Then for the weighted sum we finally have

> $$\sum_{\sigma\in\Gamma}W_\sigma\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}c(\sigma(\lambda)) =\big\langle \psi,\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}P_{J_\lambda}\big\rangle$$

Indeed we just apply $\psi$ to the same expansion formula above, now with coefficients $a(j)x^{\mu(j)}$, that is
$$\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\Big(\sum_{j\in J_\lambda}a(j)x^{\mu(i)}\Big)=\sum_{\sigma\in\Gamma}\Big(\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}a(\sigma(\lambda))\Big)x^{\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mu(\sigma(\lambda))}=\sum_{\sigma\in\Gamma}\Big(\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}a(\sigma(\lambda))\Big)x^{\mu(\sigma(\Lambda))}.$$

$$$$

**Example 1.** For your first sum, that has weights $W_{|I|}$, take $\mu(j)=1$ so $\mu(I)=|I|$. Define a linear functional $\psi$ on $\mathbb C[x]$ by $\langle \psi,x^h\rangle=W_h$, and let $P_k(x):=f(k)x+g(k)$. Then

> $$\sum_{I\subset [n]}W_{|I|}\prod_{i\in I}f(i)\prod_{i\in I^c} g(i)=\big\langle \psi,\prod_{k=1}^n P_k\big\rangle.$$

(I'd say this may be of some appeal if the $W_h$ are moments of a significant functional $\psi$, like in the linked example).

**Example 2.** For Sam Hopkins' example in comments above, we do have the analogous representation, which turns out to be no surprise. We find $\psi$ is the "extraction of $k$-th degree coefficient", $\langle \psi, P(z)\rangle=[z^k]P$, and, of course,

> $$\sum_{J\subset [n]\atop |J|=k}\prod_{j\in J}x_j=[z^k]\prod_{i=1}^n(x_iz+1).$$

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for such a detailed exposition! I will try to think whether this technique can be applied to $W_\sigma =\frac{1}{|I|+1-h}$ with $h$ the number of subsets of consecutive indices in $I$ (e.g., I={1,3,4,6,7} has h = 3), and $f(i),g(i)$ very simple linear polynomials in $i$.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it may be of use :)

Comment: Then you may try and start with weights  $|I|^ah^b$, (always with the same $P_k(x)$ ).

Comment: Then by linearity you can use the corresponding $\psi_{a,b}$ to build a functional $\Psi_m$ for $(h-|I|)^m$ (by binomial expansion), and finally $\Psi:=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\Psi_m$ for $\frac1{1-(h-|I|)}$

Comment: This is very useful! are there any references for this type of formalism?

Comment: The constraint on h(l):=the number if components of I, seems a bit hard to deal with... If you have any case of W=w(|I|,h(l)) that you can treat, maybe you can produce enough situations to cover 1/(1+|I|-h(I))...

Comment: I don't have a reference, sorry. Hopefully your paper, when it is ready! Maybe something may be found in  "umbral calculus"

Comment: I can only write $h$ in terms of Kronecker delta as $h(I)=|I|-\sum_{m=1}^{|I|-1}\delta_1(i_{m+1}-i_m)$, which depends on $I$ as an ordered sequence of integers. Indeed, this seems too hard to tackle

Comment: Rmk. In your situation the set $\Lambda$ is $[n]$, the set $X$ is $[n]\times[2]$,  partitioned in $n$ classes $X_i=\{i\}\times [2]$. If we define the exponent function $\mu:X\to\mathbb N$ as $\mu(i,j):=2^{i-1}(j-1)$, so that in $X_i$ it takes value either $0$ or $2^{i-1}$, then the additive set function deduced from $\mu$ (still denoted $\mu$) completely determines the set $I$ (by uniqueness of the binary representation).

Comment: So if the polynomials are $P_k(t):=f(k)t^{2^{k-1}}+g(k)$, every family of coefficients $\{W_I\}_{I\subset [n]}$ can be represented by some $\psi.$ The same holds true in the general setting of a partition of a finite set $X$ (using a mixed base representation). Also note that the  $\psi$ does not depend on the coefficients $f(k)$ and $g(k)$; it only depends on  the $\{W_I\}_I$ —so  e.g. for $W_I:=\frac1{1+|I|-h(I)}$  it could even be a reasonable object with a dignity of its own.

Comment: (on the contrary, a cheap exponent function $\mu(i,j)=j-1\in\{0,1\} $ for all $(i,j)$, gives as set function a cardinality, and this way you can only represent coefficients that depend on $|I|$ only) 
Disclaimer: I don’t know as useful these thoughts may be —I just hope so.